# three or five repetition in PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

in PCRE is there a better way rather than the following one to specify character repetition 3 or 5 times?

```
/(\d{3})|(\d{5})/
```

Is there a special repetition quantifier for it to have a shorter expression?

Comment: I guess no. You can however make it - `\d{3}(\d{2})?`

Comment: +1 You need to get on the board with some points.

Comment: Or you do `\d(\d{2}){1,2}` ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could also do:

Edit2: Corrected greedy specifier \d{2}`?` to be optional quantifier.

```
 /(\d{3}(?:\d{2})?)/
```

Additional comment on curly braced quantifiers -

Consider this:
An exact amount specified of the form  `{n,n}` or `{n}`
What is the impact of a greedy specifier?

Perl docs say
 `{n}?   Match exactly n times, not greedily`
 `{n}+   Match exactly n times and give nothing back (redundant)`

The impact is nothing, it has no connotation other than the exact amount must match.
Obviously there is a HOLE here.

There is also a `syntax` hole in the form of `{,n}`, that is not parsed as a quantifier,
but as a literal.

Pretty confusing since no error is ever generated in these cases.

There is a need, and use, for a quantifier construct that fits perfectly in this form:

`{n}? Match exactly n times, or match nothing`

`{,n,o,p, ..} Match the most either n,o,p, times (where n < o < p)`
`{,n,o,p, ..}? Match the least either n,o,p, times (where n < o < p)`

If this `syntax hole'` were used/filled, the OP's question could be answered by a
simple `/(\d{,3,5})/`

In a broader context, this would add imense power to regular expressions.
And probably, dramatically reduce backtracking because this list-like syntax is atomic
in nature.

An edit for @Tim Pietzcker -
Sorry I'm late with a response. I don't think there is an "exact" construct in curyly quantifiers, the notation is shortcut. There is only min/max as you suggest (correct me if I'm wrong). I can only see with a Perl regex debugger. It suggests `{n}` notation is parsed as `{n,n}` as seen by the engine. No optimization's are changed. I think this is bad and confusing notation with regard to the lazy quantifier, that according to all docs (and all docs have this), remain 'least possible' on an exact shorhand notation. I think this shorhand `{n}?` should be eliminated, or actually used for something useful - shorthand for `(?:x{n})?`. That is my point, though kind of unrelated to what your comment was.

Comment: But that's the wrong answer. The question mark makes the `{2}` quantifier lazy (which is a no-op because there isn't any variability), not optional. You need parentheses around `\d{2}`: `/\d{3}(?:\d{2})?/`

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Fixed! Thanks for pointing that out. I was working on properties \p{} just previous to this and lost focus for this one. It currently doesn't but, don't you think `{n}?` should mean exact or nothing? I don't see any construct design conflicts.

Comment: `x{2}?` is completely identical to `x{2}`. A lazy quantifier only makes a difference if there are different match possibilities (zero or one, zero or more, one or more, ...) but "exactly two, as few as possible" is identical to "exactly two" in every regard.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Posted a response above because it is too long. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

/\d{3,5}?/ maybe? Do you really need the capturing brackets?

Comment: Just a fyi, the OP said 3 or 5 times.